# How to make text inside Expanded scrollable in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

I'm busy building an app with flash cards with information on them, and I've run into a silly problem that I just can't seem to figure out.

To give context, the card Widget currently looks as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bmrc.png

As you can see, the text is cut off. I've tried changing Expanded to SingleChildScrollView, but then I end up with this scenario:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj2jC.png

I know the solution is probably very simple, but I've been fiddling for hours

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.indigo,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset(
                getCategoryImage(),
                width: 50
              ),
              Container(width: 10),
              Text(
                title,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: "Estherilla",
                  fontSize: 30,
                  color: Colors.white
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25),
              child: Text(
                content,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25,
                  color: Colors.white
                ),
              ),
            )
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "#$author",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: "Estherilla",
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Assistance would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `SingleChildScrollView` inside a `Expanded` widget like this

```
 Column(
   ...

   Expanded(
     child: SingleChildScrollView(...)
   ),

   ...
 )
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of this. Thank you good sir, it works